# Can an Oozie Action point to multiple actions?

Tags: oozie

I have an Oozie action that will call other actions.
I dont want to rewrite this as another action as they are being used individually.

```
<action name="some action">
    <Go to action 1>
    after action 1 go to action 2
    <Go to action 2>
</action>

<action name="action 2">
        <sub-workflow>
                <app-path>${SUB_APP_PATH}workflow_monthly.xml</app-path>
        <propagate-configuration/>

        </sub-workflow>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail" />
</action>

<action name="action 1">
        <sub-workflow>
                <app-path>${SUB_APP_PATH}workflow_weekly.xml</app-path>
        <propagate-configuration/>

        </sub-workflow>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

Documentation or guidance much appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your requirement?

Comment: A fork can run many actions in parallel.You can use condition node to choose your next action based on your check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure on your question, so let me know if you meant something else.

Oozie prevents having multiple actions pointing to one action. The `join` following a fork is the only exception here. I tend to try and work around this with clever workflow design and good use of properties - i.e. I'd pass `weekly` or `monthly` into the job as a property called `frequency`, and then actions 1 and 2 could be replaced with a single action:

```
<action name="action">
    <sub-workflow>
            <app-path>${SUB_APP_PATH}workflow_${frequency}.xml</app-path>
    <propagate-configuration/>

    </sub-workflow>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="fail" />
```

Obviously it's not exactly the solution you're looking for, but it's the best I've ever been able to do.

As an aside, I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to do in your workflow - why not have `some action` point to `action-1` and then have `action 1` point to `action-2`? Why do you want to go back to `some action`? Are you looking for forks? In which case:

```
<fork name="fork-actions"> <!--this replaces `some-action`-->
    <path start="action-1" />
    <path start="action-2" />
</fork>
<join name="join-fork-actions" to="end" />

<action name="action-2">
    <sub-workflow>
            <app-path>${SUB_APP_PATH}workflow_monthly.xml</app-path>
    <propagate-configuration/>

    </sub-workflow>
<ok to="join-fork-actions"/>
<error to="fail" />
```

```
<action name="action-1">
    <sub-workflow>
            <app-path>${SUB_APP_PATH}workflow_weekly.xml</app-path>
    <propagate-configuration/>

    </sub-workflow>
<ok to="join-fork-actions"/>
<error to="fail" />
```